# IndexError: list index out of range can anybody help me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am using this code to extract date and time from text file in pandas, program is not showing any issue while executing the code line by line, but when i run it as a whole it shows error index out of range. Any one who can help me
Thanks in advance

[image: This is how my data looks]

```
for line in msgs:
    if filter_message(line):
        if is_single_offer(line):
            x = line.split()
            #Get the date
            dating = x[0]
            Date.append(dating.replace(',',''))
            
            #Get the time
            timing = x[1]
            Time.append(timing)
```

Comment: Does your data have a header? Show the code you are reading the data from the file, please.

Comment: Print `x` before accesing `x[1]` and look at the content. Or - to reduce the number of outputs - catch the error with `try` and `except` and print the value if you hit the `except` block.

Comment: @Matthias but i want date and time is there any issue with data indexing?

Comment: No, but it seems as if `line` and then the value `x` don't contain data in the expected structure (e.g. an empty string, a string with no space character, ...).